# How to have a complex object as @requestBody?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have following class as my `@RequestBody` but I cannot send my request, I tried to prepare the JSON in different formats but none of them worked.

**Handler**

```
@RequestMapping("/grades")
@ResponseBody 
public Response addgrades(@RequestBody MyClass myClass){
    .....
}
```

**Back-Classes**

```
Class MyClass{
  private int code;
  private String name;
  private String fname;
  private List<Grade> grades;
  ...
}
Class Grade{
  private double grade;
  private double rate;
  private String teacher;
  ...
}
```

One of the formats that I used

```
  [
   {"code":1233,"name":"Jack","fname":"Moore"},
   {{"grade":83.33,"rate":11.11,"teacher":"Alex Jones"},     
    {"grade":77.67,"rate":12.11,"teacher":"Alex Jones"}}
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON format is incorrect. Try this one:

```
{
  "code": 123,
  "name": "myclass1",
  "fname": "the name",
  "grades": [{
    "grade": 1.0,
    "rate": 2.0,
    "teacher": "teach1"
  }, {
    "grade": 3.0,
    "rate": 4.0,
    "teacher": "teach2"
  }]
}
```